# enumerate certificates in pkcs12 and get their expiration date

Tags: shell, openssl, x509, pkcs#12

I want to list certificates from .p12 file and then use openssl x509 -enddate to output their expiration date. Here is my command:

> openssl pkcs12 -in /download/key.p12 -nokeys -passin pass:"123456"
>   -clcerts | openssl x509 -enddate

However, it just stopped after processing the first certificates, but in key.p12, there are other certificates and I want to know them all.

Is there a good way to browse all certificates and then get all of their expiration date?